# How can I connect to an Ethereum-based NFT market from my laptop using Firefox?

Tags: nft, browsers

I'm new to crypto and NFTs. I have an online wallet with Coinbase and a wallet on a USB stick using Electrum. **How can I connect to an Ethereum-based NFT market from my laptop using Firefox?** (I don't use Chrome.)

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is what I use. It's a browser plugin that manages your Ethereum accounts and connects to Web3 enabled sites. I'd say install MetaMask and then you can either create a new wallet or import an existing one (if you have), and then you can just send ETH to your MetaMask wallet. MetaMask can connect with your account to Web3 (blockchain based) sites and make it super easy to purchase stuff using ETH.

You can download MetaMask here https://metamask.io/

Comment: Thanks for this. Both Opensea and Rarible only let you link a Coinbase wallet for use from a laptop if you've got Chrome, but if it's a Metamask wallet you want to link then Opensea seem to offer a Firefox option. I will investigate. Edit: I went to install the Metamask Firefox extension but it required the permission to access my data "for all websites". Hmmmmm...

Comment: Someone asked about the "all websites" issue [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metamask/comments/g361lb/why_does_the_firefox_extension_need_to_access/). I'm not persuaded by the reply that "In order to provide its API to sites you visit, unfortunately this is the smallest permission that makes what MetaMask does possible." Many wallets don't even require that you open a web browser. (Unfortunately, though, I don't know how to connect any of those ones with an NFT marketplace, hence this question.)

Comment: I suppose installing a Metamask extension on a portable version of Firefox on a flash drive might be OK, but given that I'll be using a laptop this is the only way I have thought of so far to connect with one of the main NFT marketplaces using an ETH wallet that doesn't require Google's Chrome to be installed and may possibly be secure.

Comment: I am concerned about the privacy of the keys myself so I only connect to super well known sites. It is by far the easiest option unless you can just bid on a coin and then send ETH direct from your wallet.